# Java template engine for Markdown

Tags: java, spring-boot, templates, markdown

I am looking for options for parsing markdown template (with placeholders) ,inject data create a concrete markdown document (ex -thymeleaf for html). Are there any Java libraries to achieve this?
One option is to read the markdown template as a String and replace placeholders problematically but I am looking for more clean solution.

I found that "commonmark-java" and "flexmark-java" are capable of parsing markdown but not template engines.

Comment: @Chris As per  [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) if someone has a recommendation question,  describing the problem and mentioning what has been done so far to solve it would be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to go ahead with [thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/) (text template)